# Can you directly restore / overwrite ec2 volume from snapshot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I'm familiar with the operation of creating a new volume from a snap then mounting it separetely , but through the console or aws cli is there a way to restore a volume from a snapshot in such a way that it overwrites the volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, restore from a snapshot always creates a new volume. You can then detach the original volume (even if it's a root volume) and attach this new one under the same device name, e.g. `/dev/sda1`. Best to stop the instance before detaching/attaching the volume, however with some care it can be done for non-root volumes event without shutdown.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: To add to MLu's excellent answer, sometimes it's easier to create a new instance, unless the current instance has resources you need - private IP, ENI, etc.

Comment: Yes thank you for the help